# If any TRUE() return TRUE() according to 2 columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table looking like below:

| MONTH_YEAR | STORE_ID | BOOLEAN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/07/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/07/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/07/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/07/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/08/2022 | A | TRUE |
| 01/08/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/08/2022 | A | TRUE |
| 01/08/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/08/2022 | B | TRUE |
| 01/08/2022 | B | TRUE |
| 01/08/2022 | B | TRUE |
| 01/08/2022 | B | FALSE |

And I would like to create a new table that returns TRUE() if any TRUE() is found per store and per month, so in my example would result in:

| MONTH_YEAR | STORE_ID | SUMMARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/07/2022 | A | FALSE |
| 01/08/2022 | A | TRUE |
| 01/08/2022 | B | TRUE |

I am very new to this, so any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want a calculated table or a measure for a table visual?

Comment: A calculated table

Comment: For now I can re-create the 2 first columns of the result table with CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table[MONTH_YEAR], Table[STORE_ID])), my issue is to return the SUMMARY column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Table 2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[MONTH_YEAR],'Table'[STORE_ID]),
    "Summary",
    IF(
        CALCULATE( COUNTAX('Table','Table'[BOOLEAN]), 'Table'[BOOLEAN] = TRUE()) > 0, TRUE(), FALSE()
    )
)
```

[image]